# How to run nodejs demo project on window 7

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new with nodejs,I have some issues and please help me
before listing my issues, I've searched for some demo like

dailyjs.com/2012/05/03/windows-and-node-1/

blueashes.com/2011/web-development/install-nodejs-on-windows/

nodejs.org/ .... etc..

With first demo "Hello world" I can run nodejs server by command line, browser print "Hello world" on the screen. With next project demo on github for example

github.com/scotch-io/node-todo/tree/tut2-structure

I use command: > node path/server.js but it responses error 340

So I have 3 questions want to ask:

1 - How can I run this demo project, I've searched for 2 days and I have no any idea how to run it

2 - How can I control server like press F5 in Visual Studio then build project and run

3 - Is there any tool to manage nodejs project (I've not searched for this question, just want to have a recommend but I'm prefer coding with notepad++ )

I'm very appreciate with your help

**Edit 1:** 
After searching more solution, finally I can run this demo project by using command
and this is answer for question 1

> npm install express [path to project]

but question 2 and 3 not yet

Comment: What is the exact output you get from the `node` command?

Comment: I don't have enough population to post img, but I've solve it with my edit, thanks bro xD

Comment: `node filename.js` in command prompt or terminal does the trick.as long as you dont use extra language such as coffeescript or typescript,You don't need to compile the code you wrote because that's what script language is. simply write a code then run it via `node filename.js`